# hard drive failed. Can WinHex help me recover data and maybe rescue the drive itself?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My laptop won't boot because of a hard drive error.

The hard drive was removed and connected via USB, shows as unallocated and uninitialized under disk mgt and not recognized under my computer.

I have tried **data recovery software** such as mini tool partition, easeus, roadkill etc. Most of them say can't read disk, bad sectors, or won't recognize the drive.

**WinHex seems to be the only one I have made little progress with, initially (and sometimes) it saw the drive as unpartitioned and unallocated but lately it is showing partitions table.**

I have attached screen grabs of what the output is. I know there are bad sectors, and it says  data redundancy cyclic error (something like that).

Can anyone figure out what the disk status is and how and if I can recover data from it based on the WinHex outputs.

I have 2 chapters of my thesis in there that I didn't back up, was working on a section when the laptop won't turn on after a shutdown. My deadline is near and I am at a loss over what to do.

[image: Attached screenshot.]

[image: Attached screenshot.]

[image: Attached screenshot.]

[image: Attached screenshot.]

[image: Attached screenshot.]

Comment: Based on what you describe your HDD has failed.  Replace the HDD and restore all your other files from a backup.  Your thesis at this point is gone, in the future, backup something as important as your thesis.

Comment: The only option left is to bring the HDD to a data recovery company in your area.

Answer (score 0):

Use **spinrite**. (Paid) from grc.

It is a long shot looking at what you already did but because of your results of Winhex, I think it is worth the shot.

If after a few hours of letting Spinrite run on the drive, if you get back in, copy all important to another medium. Do NOT continue to work on the drive.

1. Run Spinrite on the drive while it is in the laptop. You boot spinrite from USB stick.
2. After Spinrite is complete, I would not boot from the HDD device but try to copy the files after booting from a **live ubuntu CD/USB**.

You might need a techie to use the Spinrite GUI; though the GUI only appears not user-friendly, it actually is provided that you read what the GUI tells you.